# I installed ubuntu 22.04 with the option of booting to either ver. 20 or 22, but that is not happening

Tags: boot

I made a bootable ubuntu ver 22.04 usb stick.  When going through the process of installing it on my dell desktop I chose the option of installing it along side the version I am currently running [20.04].
The process said I would be given the choice of which version I wanted to boot up with.  Alas... such is not the case.  It boots to my old version 20 with no choices.

Can anyone tell me what is going on?  I don't know much about Linux yet so am limited with understanding the language and procedures.  (use newbie language to reply (:?> )

Thank you for your help.
Mr. Roberts (I'm 73 and trying to learn linux)
PS I don't know what to use for tag names, my apologies.